# adding css file to php pages?

Tags: php, css, stylesheet

im new to PHP programming and im facing with a problem. 
I want to add my css file to my php page. its in folder named css. 
my fonts,pictures, etc. are on other folders. 
my php page is in folder named beginer. when i want to link my css file to this page, i need to give every classes that i wrote the specific address to them. it should be change for a every folder.
for example:

```
body{
background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
}
```

it works fine for my index.php file which is in root. but my other files which are in other folders, the address needs to be changed.
it will be like this:

```
body{
background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
```

whats the solution for this issue?
thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think you don't have understanding what PHP and CSS does. PHP just produces some data and HTTP headers describing that data. In your case, you should look at page source code; it's where PHP responsibility ends. Specifically to you problem, it's simpler to use paths relative to root: `body { background-image:url(/images/bg.jpg); }`. In this case you wouldn't have to manage "depth" of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css in php like you do in any html page.

eg :

```
<?php
      -------------------
      -------------------
 ?>
<style type="text/css">
      -------------------
      ---------
      your css code here

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add html below your php codes in order to call your css files. And for the images files inside different folder, put it in the root directory where your index.php is so you don't need to use `../` on every css. It should be something like this;

```
<?php codes goes here ?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
     background-image:url(/images/bg.jpg);
    }
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

So your root directory will consists of the following files:

- index.php
- images folder